# calculating average metric across two tables in Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have two tables, A and B, where

```
Table A:-

col1     col2
 a        1,2,3   
 b        1,4,5
 c         4 
 
 Table B:- 

 ID    metric 1
 1       231.0
 2       1123.1
 3       110
 4       1231 
 5       116
```

I have to find the mean value of `metric 1` for each `col1` value in Table A. The resulting table should contain col1 in descending order measured by avg(metric1) value from table B, using SQL

Result: -

```
col1     avg(metric1)    count
  c           1231         1
  b            526         3
  c            488         3
```

any ideas on how I can come up with a query for the same in Postgres SQL? I've tried the following query, but this does not work :

```
combined_stats AS(
select avg(metric1), count(*)
from table_b
where ID in (select col2 from table_a)
group by (select col1 from table_a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your data model!  Do not store numbers in strings!  Do not store multiple values in a string!

Let me assume that you are stuck with someone else's really bad data model.  If so, you can split the results and `join`:

```
select a.col1, avg(b.metric1), count(b.id)
from a left join
     b
     on b.id = any (regexp_split_to_array(col2, ','))
group by a.col1;
```

Note:  If `b.id` is a number, then you need to deal with type conversions, something like:

```
     on b.id::text = any (regexp_split_to_array(col2, ','))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=90529fb500ae62310c523f126c666b4c) is a db<>fiddle.